# When is $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ an identity matrix for non-square $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A\in\mathbb{R_+}^{n \times k}$ be a non-square matrix of positive entries for $n>k$. I'm interested in the properties of the matrix $B=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$.

Now $BA = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^TA = A$, and $A$ is an injective map from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. So we can find a left inverse $A^{-1}_l \in\mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ that surjectively maps $Im(A)\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k $ such that $A^{-1}_l \circ A  =AA^{-1}_l =Id_k$. So $A^{-1}_lBA = A^{-1}_lA = Id_k$. And similarly $A^TB(A^T)^{-1}_r = Id_k$.

What else can we say about $B$, especially its relationship with $A, A^T$ and $A^TA$, and when is it just the identity map?

Comment: $B$ cannot be equal to $I_n$ as $rank(B)\le k<n$.

Comment: Yeah, the rank is bounded by $k$. I'm mainly interested in $I_k$ that $B$'s restriction to $\mathbb{R}^k$ is an identity

Comment: $B \in \mathbb R^{n,n}$ so it cannot be equal to $I_k$. Maybe I misunderstood your quesiton

Comment: You are assuming $A$ has rank $k$ to even write this. Do you know that $B$ gives projection onto,the column space of $A$? This is in every linear algebra book.